# I don't know how to use rigidbody correctly

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I add Rigid body component to an object, it start passing through all objects . Is there any solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 3):

Every object need to have Collider on it. Cheers!

Comment: Which collider I have to add to an object ? There are so many colliders .

Comment: check this  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bh9ArKrPY8w  and this  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dLYTwDQmjdo
And start to use google.com search things like "Unity collider rigidbody"

Comment: Thanks bro! . I use google but couldn't find the solution , thats why I post it on this website .